# select rows (“YYYYMMDD” string format) <= today

Tags: mysql, laravel, select, eloquent

I have table "billing" that column "X" contain YYYYMMDD (VARCHAR(8), I'm not creator of the table).

```
$today = Carbon\Carbon::now();
```

How to do :

```
Select * from billing where X <= $today;
```

in Raw or Eloquent Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this as a database data

[image]

This is your Model

```
namespace App\Entities;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Date extends Model 
{
    protected $fillable = [];

}
```

This is your controller code

```
use App\Entities\Date;

public function check(Date $Date) 
    {

        $today = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

        $filterByDate = $Date->whereDate('dates','<=',$today)->get();

        dd($filterByDate);
    }
```

The data result for query is

[image]

Query Results in

```
select * from `dates` where date(`dates`) <= '2016-09-16'
```

For eloquent date filter refer [this](http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/)

Comment: I'm using eloquent $filterdate = App\Billing::whereDate('X', '<=', $today)->get(); it returns nothing, php artisan tinker freeze. Model billing has protected $table = 'billing';

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_to_date

```
 Select * from billing where str_to_date(X, '%Y%m%d') <= $today;
```

Comment: I'm using eloquent $filterdate = App\Billing::whereDate('X', '<=', $today)->get(); but nothing happened. PHP artisan tinker freeze